Deleted contacts not coming back in contact sync in SFMC
We have a contact sync set up in SFMC that brings over all records where "Emailable contact = true" (Emailable Contact parameters determined by us in a flow that marks that field true or false in Salesforce CRM)
If someone is not an emailable contact, we want to delete them from SFMC. However, they can become an emailable contact later should they opt back in. At which point, we want them to come back into the Contact sync.
I have tested this a few times by deleting a contact, and waiting for them to back through the sync. The only time those contacts come back is when I manually refresh the synced object.
Is this the only way previously deleted contacts can come back into the sync? By manually refreshing? New contacts do not seem to have this issue.

the sync every 15 mins is only syncing changes, did you change a value for a field for this contact in CRM?

That was definitely the piece I was missing! I was under the assumption that it would just continuously bring over anyone who met the requirements, not just monitor the changes. Thanks!

Question was answered by EazyE. The sync (set to every 15 minutes) only monitors changes, not just anyone who meets the requirements. I deleted the test contact from SFMC, made the test contact not meet the requirements to be "Emailable" then waited 15 minutes. I then made the contact emailable, waited another 15 minutes, and the contact was appearing correctly.
